# How I can clear the cache of Backbone relational?

Tags: caching, backbone.js, backbone-relational

How I can clear the cache of relational Backbone?
relational backbone remembers the previous values ​​after fetch

Answer (score 3):

```
Backbone.Relational.store.reset()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Backbone.Relational.store.reset();
models.fetch({
  data: {...},
  reset: true,
  success: function(models) {...}
});
```

Thanks @jax.

Answer (score 0):

`Backbone.Relational.store.reset()` removes also registered relations. If you want to clear the cache of stored models only, use this:

```
Backbone.Relational.store._collections.forEach(function each(collection) {
    collection.reset();
});
```